# Moving an execution plan between schemas

Tags: oracle, sql-execution-plan

The execution plan for one of my queries takes 12 min to create.

Is it possible to move an execution plan for a query between different schemas? Objects like tables, indexes, etc. have the same structure on each of those schemas.

Comment: 12 minutes is pretty impressive. Do you have any special optimizer settings on those databases?

Comment: Can you post the query or the plan?  I can think of some weird cases that would cause this, such as `dynamic_sampling(10)`, or an a statement with hundreds of `UNION ALL`s.

Comment: @Mat - no, no special settings that may be an issue here.

Comment: @jonearles - you are close, this is a kind of reconciliation report query which is created automaticaly using rules from external file, so optimizing a query is not an option here - that's reason why I'd like to migrate execution plan.

Comment: read about `outlines` in oracle

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that it takes 12 minutes to parse the query and generate the query plan.  That seems highly, highly unlikely.  It's incredibly unusual for the optimizer to require seconds to generate the plan let alone minutes.  My guess, though, is that it you are talking about the time that it takes to run the query not to parse it.  And if that's the case, moving the query plan wouldn't help.

Comment: I've asked db admins about the issue and they wrote that `maintenance work and tests` had place yesterday and `OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING` level could be the cause of observed db behaviour. As today plan generates in not more than 10 sec this could be right.